# python: Any downside to instantiating a class vs. referencing, if it only has constants?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python, so I apologize if this question sounds silly. This is not just plain curiosity, I have to work with code that has a class like that.

Consider a following python code snippet:

```
class _Base(object):
  constant1 = 1
  constant2 = 2
  constant3 = 3


def main():
  a = _Base    # Referencing a class
  b = _Base()  # Instantiating


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

In this particular example when _Base class does not have an `__init__()` method, is there any downside, performance-wise or otherwise, in using `b` approach as compared to `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd normally put constants inside a module instead of a class. If you need to use them for subclasses then inherit from the Base and use them, otherwise, don't instantiate the `class` as you're just using it as a kind of "namespace".

Name it something better than `_Base` and access the variables as (for eg:) `MyConstants.constant1` instead...

Answer (score 3):

Jon Clements gives the answer to how you should do this.

But to answer your actual question:

> is there any downside, performance-wise or otherwise, in using b approach as compared to a?

More important than performance is readability. If you instantiate an object, readers will think you've done so for some reason, and get side-tracked trying to figure out what `b` is being used for and what a `_Base` instance represents in your object model and so on. It won't take too long to figure out that it's useless, but "obvious" is always better than "won't take too long to figure out".

But there is a performance downside as well. It will most likely never matter in any measurable way in any program you ever write, but it's there.

First, `b` is a newly-allocated object that takes a few bytes (maybe a couple dozen), while `a` is just a new name for an already-existing object (the class itself). So, it wastes memory.

Second, constructing `b` takes a bit of time. Besides allocating that memory, you also have to call the `__new__` and `__init__` slots on `object`.

You can test the performance difference for yourself with `timeit`, but I wouldn't bother. You'll most likely find out that `b` is 20 times slower than `a` or something like that, but a 20:1 improvement in something you do one time per run that takes under a microsecond is still meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Clements answer is pretty good, but if you want, you can stay with the class, but turn all of your constants into static methods.

```
class MyConstants(object):

    @staticmethod
    def constant1():
        return 1
```

Then you can call it:

```
some_variable = MyConstants.constant1()
```

I feel that handling things like this is nicer in terms of maintainability---if you ever want to do anything other than return a constant, Jon's solution won't work, and you'll have to refactor your code. For example, you may want to change the definition of `constant1` at some point:

```
def constant1():
    import time
    import math

    current_time = time.time()        
    return math.ceil(current_time)
```

which returns the current time to the nearest second.

Anyway, sorry for the essay :)

---

So, given the comments here, I thought I'd see what the actual overhead was in doing things my way (with a factory) vs. declaring static constants vs. using properties in a class.

`time_test.py`:

```
import time

CONSTANT_1 = 1000
CONSTANT_2 = 54
CONSTANT_3 = 42
CONSTANT_4 = 3.14

class Constants(object):
    constant_1 = 1000
    constant_2 = 54
    constant_3 = 42
    constant_4 = 3.14

class Factory(object):

    @staticmethod
    def constant_1():
        return 1000

    @staticmethod
    def constant_2():
        return 54

    @staticmethod
    def constant_3():
        return 42

    @staticmethod
    def constant_4():
        return 3.14

if __name__ == '__main__':

    loops = 10000000

    # static const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(loops):
        sum = CONSTANT_1
        sum += CONSTANT_2
        sum += CONSTANT_3
        sum += CONSTANT_4

    static_const_time = time.time() - start

    # as attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(loops):
        sum = Constants.constant_1
        sum += Constants.constant_2
        sum += Constants.constant_3
        sum += Constants.constant_4

    attributes_time = time.time() - start

    # Factory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(loops):
        sum = Factory.constant_1()
        sum += Factory.constant_2()
        sum += Factory.constant_3()
        sum += Factory.constant_4()

    factory_time = time.time() - start

    print static_const_time / loops
    print attributes_time / loops
    print factory_time / loops

    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
```

Results:

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:~ ben$ python time_test.py
4.64897489548e-07
7.57454514503e-07
1.09821901321e-06
--Return--
> /Users/ben/time_test.py(71)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb)
```

So there you have it: a marginal gain (a few seconds per ten million loops) in efficiency that's probably swamped by things in other places in your code. So we've established that all three solutions have similar performance unless you care about micro-optimizations like this. (If that's the case, you're probably better off working in C.) All three solutions are readable, maintainable, and probably can be found in version control in any software company that uses Python. So the difference is down to aesthetics.

Anyway, I once lost 15% of points for a research paper in high school because my bibliography wasn't formatted correctly. The content was flawless, it just wasn't pretty enough for my teacher. I've found that one can spend their time learning rules or solving problems. I prefer solving problems.

Comment: First, you've defined a function that takes one argument whose name shadows the built-in type `object`, then defines some never-used local functions and returns `None`. So `MyConstants.constant1` is just going to raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: More seriously, using a method instead of an attribute just in case you may one day need to make it a calculated value is an anti-pattern in Python. Just use an attribute, and you can always replace it with a `@property` if you ever need to.

Comment: `def` -> `class`. Jeez take a break.

Comment: That's why I put "More seriously" on the second one. The first is just a trivial typo; the second makes your entire answer bad advice.

Comment: Sounds a bit...totalitarian.

Comment: This creates unnecessary overhead by forcing you to do a function call every time you want to access a constant.

Comment: Yes, I agree that explaining why your suggestion is considered an anti-pattern in the Python community is just like censoring the news media and killing or disappearing a few million citizens, but that's just how I roll.

Comment: For timing code, use [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) rather than subtracting `time.time` values. Besides being simpler and harder to get wrong, it also uses the best available underlying timer (which may be _much_ higher resolution than what `time.time` provides on your platform—e.g., it's 16667x better on Windows), and takes care of things like disabling GC.

Answer (score 0):

I say look out for future maintenance, and set the class to have all `@property` methods, since they'll be indistinguishable from typical constants, and allow your code to grow, since everything will be an instance of `_Base`, and wrapped in the handy `property` decorator.

```
class Base(object):
    """for now, just holds constants"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def constant1(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def constant2(self):
        return 2

    @property
    def constant3(self):
        return 3
```

Of course, my next question is...why do you need to instantiate a *class* to do that? Why not a constant defined in the method?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""this module does stuff"""

CONSTANT_1 = 1
CONSTANT_2 = 2
CONSTANT_3 = 3
```

You can reference those in methods and classes without providing them as arguments. They work as pervasive sources of data, just like a constant should. This is typically the way to avoid [magic numbers](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic-number.html).

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to make them `@property`s now. Just make them attributes, and if you ever _do_ need to change any of them into computed values, you can replace the attribute a `@property` and none of your users will see any difference. Writing 3x as much boilerplate code today just because you might need to write it some day is a waste. (Yes, it's necessary in some language, but not in Python.)

Comment: I agree 100%. My actual advice is at the bottom, but I always try to engage OP on level terms, and offer suggestions that fit the frame of reference, even if it is a bad approach in my eyes.

Comment: But you start off by saying, "I say look out for future maintenance, and set the class to have all `@property` methods." That's unnecessary. As you say, the different is indistinguishable to users of the class. But it makes the class implementation itself harder to read. There's a big downside, and absolutely no upside, so why recommend it?

Comment: OP has already overkilled the task with a class being used to provide a namespace to constants, something a module provides. The example I provided is technically valid (bad) Python, but my true intent was to offer a solution that is more "proper" once I've described *some* way of doing it that appears to fit more closely with the example provided. If you want to address boilerplate, leave a comment for OP pointing this out, or provide your own answer.

Comment: Jon Clements already provided the right answer. And I _did_ provide an answer, to make sure the OP's question was directly addressed. But an answer just says, "That's bad, so I recommend an even worse way to do it" doesn't add anything useful.

Comment: I try to balance helping OP now, and in the future. I used to just write out "the better way", but those answers typically are overlooked because they aren't framed in a way that OP will notice. So yeah, I use some less than ideal practices, and follow up with a better way to do it. The ends justify the means in this context, in my opinion.